# How can I automatically mark local extrema with pgfplots and scatter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to have TikZ automatically mark a local maximum in a fourth-degree polynomial I built using a curve-fitting tool. I am new to LaTeX and TikZ, and am a bit overwhelmed - there seem to be a dozen ways of accomplishing this.

The code Jake provided in his answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46176/pgfplots-mark-max-min-value-of-a-function) question does not seem to work for me; it works for the functions in the example, but not for mine.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[preview=false,tikz=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt=0pt
                \def\markopts{}%
                \node [min node] {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                };
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt>1000pt
                \def\markopts{}%
                \node [max node] {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                };
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,...,7},
    domain=0:7,
    axis lines*=middle
    ]       
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,...,7},
    domain=0:7,
    axis lines*=middle
    ]       
    \addplot +[mark min] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot +[mark min] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following plots:

[image]

The first plot is the one I want to highlight a maximum for. The second plot shows that it works for the minimum; the third plot is without a domain set -- you can see that it doesn't find a maximum there, either, although again it works for the minimum.

Now, while I was setting up the example, I tweaked some values.

If I change the threshold to 500 pt:

```
\documentclass[preview=false,tikz=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt=0pt
                \def\markopts{}%
                \node [min node] {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                };
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
%            \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt>1000pt
            \ifdim\pgfplotspointmetatransformed pt>500pt
                \def\markopts{}%
                \node [max node] {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                };
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,...,7},
    domain=0:7,
    axis lines*=middle
    ]       
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

then I get:

[image: threshold 500pt]

(I would be interested in knowing why this happens.)

A bit of further playing around reveals that setting it to 999pt gives the desired result:

[image: threshold 999pt]

I have to admit at this point that I don't understand the code, and have no idea if this solution is the right one or whether it will give consistent results. Perhaps someone could explain what is happening? I don't understand what the "meta value" is supposed to mean here, or even what scatter does.

How would one draw a highlighted vertical line from the horizontal axis to the maximum using this method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are some numerical inaccuracies involved here: The range of `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` should be from 0 to 1000, where 0 is the point with the lowest `meta` value (by default, the `meta` value is the same as the `y` coordinate), and 1000 is the maximum value. However, it seems that the maximum value is sometimes something along the lines of 999.9876 or 1000.0422.

I took another look at the code, and found that there's actually a better way to determine the extreme values: They're already stored in the macros `\pgfplots@metamin` and `\pgfplots@metamax`. So we can simply use `\ifx\pgfplots@metamax\pgfplotspointmeta` to check whether we have the maximum value.

To be able to use the maximum to draw a vertical line, we can place a `\coordinate` node. This can only be accessed after the axis is finished, so you'll need to put your drawing command into the `after end axis/.code={...}` option. Setting

```
after end axis/.code={
        \draw [thick, dashed, gray] (maximum) --({axis cs:0,0}-|maximum);
}
```

will draw a vertical line from the maximum to the `0` line. For boxed plots, you should use `rel axis cs:0,0` instead of `axis cs:0,0`, so the line goes all the way to the edge of the plot area.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview=false,tikz=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north,
        name=minimum
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
                \def\markopts{}%
                \coordinate (minimum);
                \node [min node] {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                };
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
        \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (maximum);
            \node [max node] {
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            };
        \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
        \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,...,7},
    domain=0:7,
    axis lines*=middle,after end axis/.code={
        \draw [thick, dashed, gray] (maximum) --({axis cs:0,0}-|maximum);
    }
    ]       
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,...,7},
    domain=0:7,
    axis lines*=middle
    ]       
    \addplot +[mark min] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        after end axis/.code={
            \draw [thick, dashed, gray] (maximum) --({rel axis cs:0,0}-|maximum);
        }
    ]
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot +[mark min] plot {0.001826*x^4-0.02873*x^3+0.1066*x^2+0.03454*x+0.003613};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Yay! Too late again :)