# A problem with pgfplots and coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using Jake's code in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55352/3954) to [How can I automatically mark local extrema with pgfplots and scatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55349/3954). Using the `mark max` style I can retrieve the value for the y-coordinate of the maximum for a function using `\pgfplots@metamax`.

Having this value I can use it, for example, to add nodes using the `axis cs` coordinate system, as the code below shows; however, I cannot use those nodes as coordinates for a new `\addplot` (uncommet the commented-out line with `\addplot` and you'll get an error).

How can I use those named nodes for an `\addplot`?

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
        \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (maximum);
            \node [max node] {
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            };
        \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
        \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    }
}
\makeatother

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{cubic}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{-2*(#1+2)*(#1+2)*(#1-2)+40}%
}

\begin{document}        

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  xtick={-2.5,2.5},
  ytick={\empty},
  domain=-2.5:2.5,
  ymin=-1,
  xmin=-4,
  xmax=3,
  clip=false,
] 
% The curve
\addplot [mark max,draw=red,name path=A] plot {cubic(x)};
\makeatletter
\node (A) at (axis cs:-2.5,\pgfplots@metamax) {A};
\node (B) at (axis cs:2.5,\pgfplots@metamax) {B};
%\addplot[name path=B] coordinates {(A) (B)};% doesn't work
\makeatother
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps I am using the wrong approach here. What I want to do is what follows:

I have the graph of a function `A` drawn using `\addplot`; this path is named using `name path=A`. I need to add another `\addplot` (that will be named `B`) defined by two points whose x-coordinates are known but whose y-coordinates are calculated adding positive or negative shifts to the y-coordinate for the maximum of `A`. Then I will use the `fillbetween` library to fill the area between `A` and `B`. How can this be done?

Comment: `coordinates` read literal coordinate expressions but A,B are TikZ referrals. Maybe simply `\path[name path=B] (A) -- (B);` ?

Comment: I think the problem here is that `\pgfplots@metamax` isn't fixed until all the `\addplot` commands have been evaluated. The `\node` commands are stored and only executed after the `\addplot` evaluation is complete, independently of whether they're placed before or after the `\addplot` commands in the code.

Comment: @percusse Yes, I ended up using a simple `\path` in my real case use; it didn't cooperated well with some `soft clip` options, but I can live with that :). WOuld you write an answer?

Comment: @Jake Thanks. Would it be possible to somehow use `\addplot`s in an `after end axis/.code={}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, sorry, I didn't get what exactly you mean with "adding positive or negative shifts to the y-coordinate for the maximum of `A`". And what problems did you have with the `soft clip` option? As far as I can follow I don't think that these problems weren't there if you would have used the `\addplot` command to `name path` B instead of using percusse's solution.