# One or selected few local optima automation in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to automate min/max values using the code here:
[How can I automatically mark local extrema with pgfplots and scatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55349/how-can-i-automatically-mark-local-extrema-with-pgfplots-and-scatter)

1. The horizontal line appears at height of the label instead of the points (in MWE2)
2. Numerical issues regarding finding of min/max values on tikz are elicited here (in MWE3) so I guess I could go back to the > 500pt concept.  An alternative that could be interesting is to only label *one* of the minima, say the first one.

I tried to introduce \ifx\first\undefined and \newbool{first} with true false switches but it does not affect the markings.

Only the first would already be something but even better if I could choose them.

```
\documentclass[preview=false,tikz=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{isFirst}


\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north,
        name=minimum
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
\ifbool{isFirst}{
%\boolfalse{isFirst}  % this does not actually disable next labels
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (minimum);
            \node [min node] {
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            };
}
{
\def\markopts{mark=none}
}
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (maximum);
            \node [max node] {
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            };
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \booltrue{isFirst}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-100:100,
            axis lines*=middle,after end axis/.code={
                \draw [thick, dashed, gray] (maximum) --({axis cs:0,0}-|maximum);
            }
            ]       
            \addplot +[mark max,samples=5000] plot {sin(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \booltrue{isFirst}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-100:100,
            axis lines*=middle
            ,after end axis/.code={
                \draw [thin, loosely dashed, gray] (minimum) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-minimum);
                \draw [thin, loosely dashed, gray] (minimum) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-minimum);
            }
            ]       
            \addplot +[mark min,samples=5000] plot {sin(8*x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \booltrue{isFirst}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-100:100,
            axis lines*=middle
            ]       
            \addplot +[mark min,samples=5000] plot {sin(50*x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
``
```