# pgfplots: updating and accessing a macro definition across different interations of plotting points

Tags: pgfplots, macros

I'd like to make data-dependent plot annotations using pgfplots.  For example, the MWE below is a failed attempt at counting the number of points in a scatter plot with y-coordinate greater than 0:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
  ]
  % a counter for the number of pts w/ y-coord > 0
  \xdef\PtsYGreaterThanZero{0}
  \addplot[
    only marks,
    mark=o,
    blue,
    visualization depends on={y > 0 ? \PtsYGreaterThanZero+1 : \PtsYGreaterThanZero} \as \thisplotcounter,
    nodes near coords={\xdef\PtsYGreaterThanZero{\thisplotcounter}\pgfmathprintnumber{\PtsYGreaterThanZero}},
    ]  coordinates {
           (1,1)
           (2,0)
           (3,1)
           (4,0)
           (5,1) };
    % a data-dependent annotation
    \node[anchor=east,align=left,font=\footnotesize,purple] at (rel axis cs:1,0) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\PtsYGreaterThanZero} points\\greater than 0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the labels to read 1,1,2,2,3 (a running count of the number of points with y-coordinate > 0), with a final annotation (purple) of "3 points greater than 0"; not the 1,0,1,0,1 and "0 points greater than 0" that appears.  The output behaves as if the the original definition of

```
\PtsYGreaterThanZero
```

(0) is used for each iteration of plotting points, although to my eye the code reads as if the code segment in "nodes near coords=" of

```
\xdef\PtsYGreaterThanZero{\thisplotcounter}
```

could redefine

```
\PtsYGreaterThanZero
```

on each iteration to hold an updated cumulative count of the number of points with y-coordinate > 0.

I've tried to get what amounts to a counter across plotted points to work via several different methods---pgfkeys, [fancier attempts at re-definition of global macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51733/global-renewcommand-equivalent-of-global-def), use of "scatter/@pre marker code/.code=" and similar entities---all to no avail (they all appeared to almost work except for failing in the same manner as the example above: namely, not updating an original definition of a counter, perhaps due macro definitions not persisting across groups---something I don't understand and don't see in the pgfplots manual).

The bottom line question seems to be this: *is it possible to define a macro in pgfplots that can be updated in one point-plotting iteration and available to the next iteration (and also be available at some point after the plotting is completed)?*

It seems to me that such a mechanism could be used to make all sorts of automatic data-dependent plot annotations, such as (as another example) finding and labeling extrema of plotted functions (e.g. update a macro that stores extrema values if a currently plotted point possesses a new extreme), but at least [one proposed method for finding extrema](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46176/pgfplots-mark-max-min-value-of-a-function) appears to circumvent any need to explicitly update a value across plotting iterations.

More generally, where can one learn more about what is going on behind the scenes of the pgfplots styles such as

- point meta
- nodes near coords
- visualization depends on
- execute at begin plot
- scatter/@pre marker code/.code

and so forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `point meta={TeX code={...}}` to do the counting. For `nodes near coords` the result is expected in `\pgfplotspointmeta`, so it must be defined in the code. The rest is `\pgfmath...` stuff.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
  ]
  % a counter for the number of pts w/ y-coord > 0
  \xdef\PtsYGreaterThanZero{0}
  \addplot[
    only marks,
    mark=o,
    blue,
    point meta={TeX code={\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(y>0,\PtsYGreaterThanZero+1,\PtsYGreaterThanZero)}%
                    \xdef\PtsYGreaterThanZero{\pgfmathresult}\edef\pgfplotspointmeta{\pgfmathresult}}},
    nodes near coords,
    ]  coordinates {
           (1,1)
           (2,0)
           (3,1)
           (4,0)
           (5,1) };
    % a data-dependent annotation
    \node[anchor=east,align=left,font=\footnotesize,purple] at (rel axis cs:1,0.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\PtsYGreaterThanZero} points\\greater than 0};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```