# Automatic showing of y-values on a graph on specific x-Positions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, asymptote

i use pgfplots to create plots of huge data sets. It reads from csv-files with about 13000 lines. What I want to achieve is to show the y-Value on a given x-value.

Hope this picture describes, what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is, what I do to create the plots:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest,
    tick label style={font=\sffamily},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                font={\sffamily},
                every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
                width=\textwidth,
                axis line style=thin,
                axis line style={gray!30},
                axis y line = center,
                axis x line = center,
                tick label style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont}},
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,-0.03)},anchor=north, font={\tiny}},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south, font={\tiny}},
                xlabel=time,
                ylabel=values,
                every y tick/.style={gray!30},
                ytick={-550,-500,...,1350},
                xtick={0,1000,...,12840},
                no markers,
                every axis plot/.append style={ultra thin},
                every axis/.append style={font=\sffamily},
                axis on top=false,
                font={\sffamily},
                xmin=0, xmax=12900,
                ymin=-550, ymax=1350,
            ]
            \addplot  table[col sep=semicolon, x index = {0}, y index = {1}]{P1.CSV};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do this automatically without putting the y-value in the graph manually?
I don't even have an idea for search words I could google.

Comment: It looks like the points you want marked are the extremas, I would have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46176/pgfplots-mark-max-min-value-of-a-function

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I gave these points just as examples but I would need the y-values on different x-positions.

Comment: Would it be OK to give the index (i.e. row number in file) instead of x-value?

Comment: Would be ok, yes.

Comment: When replying to a specific user, it's generally best to write an at-sign followed by the username, e.g. @schmendrich, otherwise that user wont be notified. Tab-completion of usernames is available, you can only ping one user per comment. (You as the owner of the post is always notified of new comments.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a second `\addplot` that only plots at given row numbers (or rather, at specific `\coordindex`es), due to an `x filter`:

```
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark size=1pt,
          nodes near coords,
          x filter/.code={
          \ifnum \coordindex=150
          \else
            \ifnum \coordindex=380
            \else
              \def\pgfmathresult{}
            \fi
           \fi                            
           }]
           table[x index = {0}, y index = {1}]{somedatafileIhadlyingaround.dat};
```

The `\ifnum`s say that if `\coordindex` is either 150 or 380, then do nothing, otherwise do `\def\pgfmathresult{}` which means no point is plotted.

`nodes near coords` by default prints the y-value next to the point. You can change the style of those nodes with `every node near coord/.style={...}`.

You might want to add `filter discard warning=false` to the `axis` options if you don't want a lot of warnings about discarded coordinates in the `.log` file.

Note I commented settings for ticks and axis limits, as the datafile I used had a very different range.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest,
    tick label style={font=\sffamily},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                font={\sffamily},
                every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
                width=\textwidth,
                axis line style=thin,
                axis line style={gray!30},
                axis y line = center,
                axis x line = center,
                tick label style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont}},
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,-0.03)},anchor=north, font={\tiny}},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south, font={\tiny}},
                xlabel=time,
                ylabel=values,
                every y tick/.style={gray!30},
%                ytick={-550,-500,...,1350},
%                xtick={0,1000,...,12840},
                every axis plot/.append style={ultra thin},
                every axis/.append style={font=\sffamily},
                axis on top=false,
                font={\sffamily},
%                xmin=0, xmax=12900,
%                ymin=-550, ymax=1350,
                filter discard warning=false  % <-- disables warnings about discarded coordinates
            ]
            % note +[mark=none], and removed "no markers" from axis options
            \addplot +[mark=none] table[x index = {0}, y index = {1}]{somedatafileIhadlyingaround.dat};
            % add second plot for marks and labels
            \addplot [only marks,mark=*,mark size=1pt,
                      nodes near coords,
                      x filter/.code={
                         \ifnum \coordindex=150
                         \else
                            \ifnum \coordindex=380
                            \else
                               \def\pgfmathresult{}
                            \fi
                         \fi                            
                     }]
                     table[x index = {0}, y index = {1}]{somedatafileIhadlyingaround.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider as an alternative this `Asymptote` `MWE`:

```
// ylabs.asy
// 
// run 
// asy ylabs.asy
// 
// to get ylabs.pdf image
// 
settings.tex="pdflatex";

import graph;
size(10cm,8cm,IgnoreAspect);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(8pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");
pen linePen=deepblue+0.8bp;

string data="p15000.csv";
file in=input(data).line().csv();
real[][] a=in; a=transpose(a);
real[] xPos=    {0.38    , 0.53     , 0.7     ,};
pair[] labelPos={plain.E, plain.W, plain.NE,};
guide g=graph(a[0],a[1]);
draw(g,linePen);
xaxis("Time",0,1.2,RightTicks(Step=0.1,step=0.05,OmitTick(0)));
yaxis("Values",LeftTicks(Step=100,step=50));

real[] t; pair p;
// adding a point of the minimum to the list
t=mintimes(g); 
p=point(g,t[1]);
xPos.push(p.x);
labelPos.push(plain.S);
// adding a point of the maximum to the list
t=maxtimes(g); 
p=point(g,t[1]);
xPos.push(p.x);
labelPos.push(plain.N);

for(int i=0;i<xPos.length;++i){
    t=times(g,xPos[i]);
    p=point(g,t[0]);
    dot(p,UnFill);
    label("$"+format("%4i",round(p.y))+"$",p,labelPos[i]);
}
shipout(bbox(Fill(paleyellow)));
```

The placement of the marks is governed by
their positions collected in `xPos` array 
and their corresponding orientation in `labelPos` array.
Also a code included to automatically find and add marks 
for the `min/max y` value 
(the orientations of the labels are also added manually).

This `MWE` was tested with about 15000 
sample points of data in `p15000.csv` file with no problems, here is the result:

[image]

This smaller `points.csv` file which produces similar shape can be used for testing :

```
0.007,4.149
0.075,0
0.111,-141.079
0.175,-331.95
0.245,-468.88
0.278,-506.224
0.358,-477.178
0.377,-460.581
0.392,-70.539
0.394,4.149
0.441,4.149
0.519,0
0.521,112.033
0.601,946.058
0.604,875.519
0.625,867.22
0.663,829.876
0.769,800.83
0.764,721.992
0.781,639.004
0.795,-49.793
0.816,4.149
0.84,4.149
0.863,4.149
0.901,-58.091
0.927,4.149
0.96,0
1.047,4.149
1.13,0
```

Comment: Stunning. I just don't understand the code ;-) Never used Asymptote before.

Comment: @schmendrich: Asymptote has its roots in `METAPOST`,
but its code uses C++/python-like commands,
for example, `real[] xPos={0.38,0.53,0.7,};`
declares an array of real values and initializes it with 3
values. After that `xPos[0]` will be set to `0.38`;
`for(int i=0;i<xPos.length;++i)` is a basic for-loop
to run `i` from 0 to xPos.length, etc. Does it really look cryptic?
Anyway, feel free to ask, if interested.