# Mark max/min value of a function with logarithmic scale

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to mark the maximum or minimum value of a function in pgfplots. For linear scale this question has been answered by [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46176/pgfplots-mark-max-min-value-of-a-function/46182#46182). How to adapt/generalize this also for logarithmic scale?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
                \def\markopts{}%
                \pgfmathsetmacro\result{}
                \node [min node] {
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
                };
            \else
                \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
        \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \node [max node] {
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\xvalue},%
                \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
            };
        \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
        \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xmin=1,xmax=4]
    \addplot +[mark min, every node near coord/.style=] plot {5+(x-2)^2};
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {-x^2+5*x+5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ymode=log,
 xmin=1,xmax=4]
    \addplot +[mark min, every node near coord/.style=] plot {5+(x-2)^2};
    \addplot +[mark max] plot {-x^2+5*x+5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
The left picture with linear scale is perfect. In the right picture with logarithmic scale the value is not written correct.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Replace the `\pgfplotspointmeta`s with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}`s.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!
Maybe a follow up question: For a plot with small values we get the min marked as 0: 
`\addplot +[mark min, every node near coord/.style=,samples=501] plot {0.0005+(x-2)^2};`
How can this be fixed?

Comment: This is because of your chosen `fixed` format for `pgfmathprintnumber`. Change it e.g. to `std,precision=2,zerofill`.